# What is the difference between these create service method in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, service, angular8

I'm new about Angular, I have a question:

Method1:

```
@Injectable()

export class classA {
    constructor(
      private service1: Service1,
      private service2: Service2) {
}
}
```

in app.module

```
providers: [
 {
      provide: classA ,
      useFactory: authServiceFactory,
      deps: [ RoleService, LogService ]
 }
 ]

export function authServiceFactory(roles: RoleService, log: LogService) {
   const service = new AuthenticationService(roles, log);
   return service;
}
```

Method2:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class classA{
   constructor(
      private service1: Service1,
      private service2: Service2)
}
```

and

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class Service1{
}
```

and

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class Service2{
}
```

and no provider in app.module.

I wonder what is the different of those method. I have tried method 1 working as well as method 2.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in the scoping of the service

This will inject the same instance of the service into all components. This is known as a singleton:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
}
```

This will inject the same instance of the service into all components **in that module**:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [ MyService ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

If you only have one module - `AppModule` - there is no difference between the two approaches - they are equivalent. It is recommended to declare all services as `providedIn: 'root'` in this scenario.

If you have multiple modules, you can declare a singleton service, and also choose to provide a module-specific version in one of your modules by overriding it in the module `providers: []`.

Take this example:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyService {
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FeatureComponentA,
    FeatureComponentB
  ],
  providers: [
    MyService
  ]
})
export class MyFeatureModule { }


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    OtherComponentA,
    OtherComponentB
  ]
})
export class MyOtherModule { }
```

`ComponentA`, `ComponentB`, `OtherComponentA`, `OtherComponentB` will all receive the same instance of `MyService` when it is injected.

`FeatureComponentA` and `FeatureComponentB` will receive a second instance of `MyService` because the provider is declared in the module that the components are declared in.